# flex 4 status ( use as beta? )

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

My company is considering upgrading to flex 4 ( mainly to use the richtextlayout ) I would like to know from your experiance what is the status of the product ( how far is it from official release ) and do you recomend using it now or wait till its complete its beta stage

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using flex 4 beta 2 for our upcoming project. 
I must admit that it's not yet production stable, there are bugs, and some of them are showstoppers. (we had some problems with data grids at least).
Though it's quite usable and works.

So, if your new project is a long-standing one and you're ready to update from time to time to the latest nightly, so go for flex 4. It's very likely that Adobe will release the final version in 2-3 months timeframe and you can easily switch to it.

If your only concern is a TLF-enabled text area, then consider as an option porting using TLF directly in your flex 3 project. That was the way I've chosen for my last project.
I've backported `RichEditableText` component to flex 3 from flex 4. It wasn't that hard, cause it had little dependencies on flex 4.

Comment: Depending on the languages you want to support, TLF should be used for all controls (buttons, labels, lists, etc.), not just the rich text control.

Comment: It should be noted that occasionally the nightly builds DO break things you're working on (renames mostly) and this can be somewhat disturbing, but it's probably best to keep atop the framework changes gradually (as opposed to switching directly from beta 2 -> beta 3 when it's released).

The big plus with working from the nightly builds is that you can learn a little something extra about the framework by reading the changelogs that are released with each build:

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4